# Draw lines in drawrect() above image in UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, layer, drawrect

I'm trying to draw lines from an array (like in paint), and that under that area was a visible image, a kind of background:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {...  for line in fetchedResults {
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, line.widt as CGFloat)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGFloat(line.startx), CGFloat(line.starty))
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGFloat(line.endx), CGFloat(line.endy))
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, line.color.CGColor)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
```

}

of cause, it is possible to draw image before drawing the lines, but that means each time the array of lines if changed e.g. user draws smth, the image will be redrawn with the lines, and that takes much time .

is it possible to draw some layer under drawrect() which will be static and redrawn only when it is requested ?

Comment: Add your background and your drawing as two different layers.

Comment: the upper layer with lines has to be redrawn each time the array of lines is changed, but adding layers will make it static

Comment: I don't think you understood what I wrote. Do not draw these lines in the same class that holds your background image.

Comment: You can use UIView as work around.UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0.5)];. I agree its work around but its simple.

Comment: Mike, do you mean creating two uiviews, one for lines and one for background image? if yes, either on will not be seen, or one have to make lines uiview transparent, which is not good

Comment: Ian, how then I will make this background image visible? If I create separate UIView class, it will require another object , which will cover or will be covered with one, where lines are drawn, and will be not visible .